# Mod rewrite only working for some pages

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to remove the .php extension on my files.
I've got a simple site with a couple of pages running locally and a simple htaccess rule - most pages work correctly but there are two that don't work and continue to display .php no matter what. I don't have any folders with this same name as these pages. My html has links to .php files (e.g. contact.php) and I don't want to change this if I don't have to.

For both these examples I have typed out the url (including .php) so I don't know why one starts off without the php and contact doesn't. Also is it normal to go through the rules 2x?
Thanks

htaccess:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [NC,L,QSA]
```

My apache error log (edited for space let me know if I cut out anything useful)

```
[rewrite:trace3] strip per-dir prefix: C:/wamp/www/test.site/about-us -> about-us
[rewrite:trace3] applying pattern '^(.*)$' to uri 'about-us'
[rewrite:trace4] RewriteCond: input='C:/wamp/www/test.site/about-us' pattern='!-d' => matched
[rewrite:trace4] RewriteCond: input='C:/wamp/www/test.site/about-us.php' pattern='-f' => matched
[rewrite:trace2] rewrite 'about-us' -> 'about-us.php'
[rewrite:trace3] add per-dir prefix: about-us.php -> C:/wamp/www/test.site/about-us.php
[rewrite:trace2] strip document_root prefix: C:/wamp/www/test.site/about-us.php -> /about-us.php
[rewrite:trace1] internal redirect with /about-us.php [INTERNAL REDIRECT]
[rewrite:trace3] strip per-dir prefix: C:/wamp/www/test.site/about-us.php -> about-us.php
[rewrite:trace3] applying pattern '^(.*)$' to uri 'about-us.php'
[rewrite:trace4] RewriteCond: input='C:/wamp/www/test.site/about-us.php' pattern='!-d' => matched
[rewrite:trace4] RewriteCond: input='C:/wamp/www/test.site/about-us.php.php' pattern='-f' => not-matched
[rewrite:trace1] pass through C:/wamp/www/test.site/about-us.php

[rewrite:trace3] strip per-dir prefix: C:/wamp/www/test.site/contact.php -> contact.php
[rewrite:trace3] applying pattern '^(.*)$' to uri 'contact.php'
[rewrite:trace4] RewriteCond: input='C:/wamp/www/test.site/contact.php' pattern='!-d' => matched
[rewrite:trace4] RewriteCond: input='C:/wamp/www/test.site/contact.php.php' pattern='-f' => not-matched
[rewrite:trace1] pass through C:/wamp/www/test.site/contact.php
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you aren't typing in .php along with the file name or that there is a link to it that way in your html or forms with the php extension.

What you can do is check for the full file name and if it's there redirect back to the extension-less URI.

I made some changes, you can try this code instead.

```
Options -MultiViews
DirectoryIndex index.php

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /([^&\ ]+).php
RewriteRule .* /%1? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ $1.php [NC,L,QSA]
```

So even if you type in `/contact.php` it will redirect back to `/contact`

Comment: Thanks alot this is working perfectly all the links are now working in the same way - correctly.